# How can I Call Mobile Number on Click Expandable Listview Child Item

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I want to develop Expandable `Listview` Application. I have some Java Code. But I don't know how to call Mobile Number on Click Expandable Listview Child Item. Such as, I want to Call Mobile Number of "Md. Nasir Uddin", "Md. Selim Khan" "Latif Sarker", "Faruk Ahmed" "Monir Akram".

**Here is My Java Code.**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{

 private SearchView search;
 private MyListAdapter listAdapter;
 private ExpandableListView myList;
 private ArrayList<SectionItem> section = new ArrayList<SectionItem>();

 ExpandableListView expandableList = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        expandableList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableList);

      SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
      search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
      search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
      search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
      search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
      search.setOnCloseListener(this);

      //display the list
      displayList();
      //expand all Groups
      expandAll();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        //method to expand all groups
     private void expandAll() {
      int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
       myList.expandGroup(i);
      }
     }

     //method to expand all groups
     private void displayList() {

      //display the list
      loadSomeData();

      //get reference to the ExpandableListView
      myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
      //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
      listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, section);
      //attach the adapter to the list
      myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     }

     private void loadSomeData() {

      ArrayList<EntryItem> items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();

        items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        section.add(new SectionItem("Family Member", items));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Md. Nasir Uddin", "+88569842525", "+6525412698", "nasir256@gmail.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Md. Selim Khan", "+7269874524", "+5825478569", "selim.265@gmail.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Abdul Alim", "+2214569852", "+636598745", "alim.khan25@yahoo.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Abdul Mannan", "+3698521455", "+2569514457", "manan.goni8@gmail.com", ""));

        items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        section.add(new SectionItem("Friends List", items));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Latif Sarker", "+8925824582", "+256992025", "latif.sarker5@yahoo.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Hossain Ali", "+2547896514", "+354125824", "hossain368@yahoo.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Faruk Ahmed", "+3541269872", "+589314255", "faruk.jony@yahoo.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Ismail Hossain", "+86713373326", "+8625478965", "ismail.hossain5@gmail.com", ""));

        items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        section.add(new SectionItem("Relative List", items));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Monir Akram", "+2536974144", "+2514796352", "monir25@gmail.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Aminul Islam", "+21478933544", "+36597452144", "Aminul256@gmail.com", ""));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Kawsar Farhad", "+2145879325", "+25698472254", "kawsar.farhad5@gmail.com", ""));

     }

     @Override
     public boolean onClose() {
      listAdapter.filterData("");
      expandAll();
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
      listAdapter.filterData(query);
      expandAll();
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      listAdapter.filterData(query);
      expandAll();
      return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Dont tag java code as jscript because they are not the same, format your code properly and unless you are using somer diff libs, dont add to the code standard API imports.

Answer (score 0):

Set click listener to the listview to fire a DIAL intent, this will open the Dialer app with the mobile number entered

```
mListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int
            childPosition, long id) {
        String number = mAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getMobileNumber();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Or u can use Intent.ACTION_CALL instead of Intent.ACTION_DIAL to call the number directly, but this will require the permission  to be added to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks For give me Sample Code. But This Line not Work. Show Error.

String number = mAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getMobileNumber();

Comment: Change .getMobileNumber() to the method of EntryItem object that returns mobile phone number, and mAdapter to listAdapter

Comment: How can I Change .getMobileNumber() to the method of EntryItem object that returns mobile phone number, and mAdapter to listAdapter. Please Write Sample Code